# write after end error at events.js:174 when trying to pipe read stream to express get api response on server

Tags: express, npm, stream

I'm getting data from a read stream and using pipe to send it to the response. It works for the first time but when I send the request again, node crashes with "write after end" error.

```
var lzma = require('lzma-native');
var compressor = lzma.createCompressor();

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000,function(){console.log('Listening to PORT 3000');});
app.use(cors());


//REST API WITH READSTREAM - COMPRESSION
app.get('/historyData',historyData);

function historyData(req,res){
    var readHist = db.createReadStream({key:'DATAKEY1'});
    readHist.pipe(compressor).pipe(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I defined the compresssor variable globally, so when I called the api again, because the stream ended during my first call, I ended up getting the error.

To resolve the issue, just define the compressor variable locally inside the "historyData" function, and that should resolve the issue.